In the slick slider when we click the image left and right space in the mobile, the slide has been pause. why? How to fix that
In the slick slider when we click the image left and right space in the mobile, the slide has been pause. why? How to fix that
$('.people-slider').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '0',
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrow:false,
   pauseOnHover: false,
  infinite: true,
  autoplay: true,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  touchMove: true,
  variableWidth: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 3000,
  speed: 500, // Transition speed in milliseconds
  cssEase: 'ease',
   swipe: true, // Enables touch swipe
    draggable: true, // Enables mouse drag for desktop
    swipeToSlide: true, // Allows slides to move smoothly
    touchThreshold: 10,
   pauseOnFocus: false,// Adjusts the swipe sensitivity// CSS easing function
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1182,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        arrow:false,
        variableWidth: false,
        centerMode: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        focusOnSelect: true,
         touchMove: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 767,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        variableWidth: false,
        centerMode: true, // Enable center mode in mobile view
        centerPadding: '20px',
        dots: true,
        arrow:false,
        autoplay:true,
        autoplaySpeed: 1000,
        pauseOnHover: false,
         pauseOnFocus: false,
        focusOnSelect: true,
        touchMove: true
        
      }
    }
  ]


The question is not clear. Perhaps adding a screen recording and a JSFiddle link might help.
